# Using an integrating factor to solve $t \frac{dy}{dt} +3y = 9t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem $$t \frac{dy}{dt} +3y = 9t , \qquad y(1)=4.$$

So far I put it into standard form:

$$ \frac{dy}{dt}+ \frac{3}{t}y = 9$$

We can take
$$p(t)= \int \frac{3}{\tau} d\tau =e^3lnt =t^3.$$

Then distributing gives

$$t^3 \frac{dy}{dt}+t^3 \frac{3}{t}y = t^3(9t).$$

Am I on the right track? Also I am unsure of what to do next.

Comment: just caught that unsure where to go from here

Comment: The point of the integrating factor method is to transform the left side of the equation into the derivative of *something*. Specifically that something is $e^{p(t)} y(t)$. Do you see how to proceed then?

Comment: Not from what I have here

Comment: You have changed the equation to $\frac{d}{dt} \left ( e^{p(t)} y(t) \right ) = 9t^4$. Now integrate both sides from $1$ (the time of the initial condition) to $t$. (Technically you should do this with a dummy integration variable like $s$.) On the left side you get $e^{p(t)} y(t) - e^{p(1)} y(1)$, by the FTC. On the right side you have an integral you can evaluate. This lets you solve for $y(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ t\dfrac{dy}{dt}+3y=9t
\\ \dfrac{dy}{dt}+\dfrac{3}{t}y=9
\\ \boxed{u(t)=e^{\int{\frac{3}{t}\,dt}}=e^{3\ln{t}}=t^3} $$
....
$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} (t^3\;y)=9t^3
\\ \int{\dfrac{d}{dt} (t^3\;y)\,dt}=9 \int{t^3\,dt} $$

Back to your ED
$$ y\,t^3 = 9\,\dfrac{t^4}{4}+c
\\ \color{blue}{y(t)=\dfrac{9}{4}t+\dfrac{c}{t^3}} $$

Comment: Sorry, my first procedure was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The integrating factor is $e^{\int\frac3tdt}=e^{3\ln t}=t^3.$

Answer (score 0):

The integrating factor $\mu(t)$ for $y'(t) + P(t) y = Q(t)$ is
$$\exp \int_{t_0}^t p(\tau) \,d\tau.$$
Rearranging the original o.d.e. into the above form gives that $P(t) = \frac{3}{t}$, so in this case (taking $t_0 = 1$) the factor is
$$\exp \int_1^t \frac{3}{\tau} d\tau = e^{3 \log t} = t^3.$$
Multiplying through, the l.h.s. becomes
$$t^3\frac{dy}{dt} + 3t^2 y = \frac{d}{dt}\left(t^3 y\right),$$
so this is indeed the correct integrating factor.

Comment: where did t^4 come from?

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the catch.

Comment: also shouldn't the rhs just be t^3(9)?

Comment: No, the equation is just declaring how one can rewrite the l.h.s.

Comment: And what would the next step be

Comment: The above shows that your equation can be written as $\frac{d}{dt}(t^3 y) = 9t$, so you can solve by integrating w.r.t. $t$, so that no derivatives occur, and then solving for $y$. Note that when you integrate, you'll pick up a constant of integration, and this will be fixed by your initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

take your differential equation multiply by $p$ to get $$pt\frac{dy}{dt} + 3py = 9tp. \tag 1$$ multiply by $p$ and require that $$\frac{d(tp)}{dt} = 3p$$ you can simplify to $$t\frac{dp}{dt} = 2p$$ which has solution $p= t^2.$

now $(1)$ can be rewritten as $$\frac{d (t^3y)}{dt} = 9t^3. $$ integrating from $1$ to $t$ gives $$t^3y - 4 = \frac94(t^4-1) \text{ or } y = \frac7{4t^3} +\frac94t.$$

---

here is the verification. $$y = \frac7{4t^3} +\frac94t, \quad \frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{21}{4t^4} + \frac94, \quad t\frac{dy}{dt} + 3y = -\frac{21}{4t^3} + \frac{9t}4 +\frac{21}{4t^3} + \frac{27t}{4} = 3t$$

Comment: unsure of what you did here however it is not the correct answer

Comment: @Alex, thanks for catching the error. check the answer now.

Comment: Thank you very much that is correct even though you did it differently then I know how to.

Comment: @Alex, the point is to write the lys as a derivative of something. that is why we multiplied by $p$ so that lhs = $\frac{d(tpy}{dt}.$  i just did not divide by $t$ first.